# SQLCE - Ignoring query execution

Tags: sql-server-ce

Deploying database(*.sdf) to Pocket PC WM 5.0.   Via C# i am attempting to DELETE records.   The DELETE query returns that 5 rows are affected(there are 5 rows).  However, when i view database in Pocket PC under its Query Tool the rows remain.   No error or issue arise at my code level.

What is missing?  It is the right database because if i rename or delete i get an erro on open.   What's wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could show us the code you have written to delete the records.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the DELETE in a transaction, and forgetting to .Commit() it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you execute the query and calling the right command.

Comment: Godsake, this question is 3 years. Didn't see that.